# Xamarin.Forms controls disappear when navigate back to a page on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, navigation, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm building an application with Xamarin.Forms and a Portable Class Library. The app can be used on Android, iOS and UWP.

I made a page that works correct on each platform: 
[image]

After clicking an item in the ListView, a new page will be opened:

> Navigation.PushAsync(new CourseInfoPage(ID));

When that page is opened and I press the "Back-button" and navigate back to the page shown above, it looks like this:
[image]

So some controls disappear when I'm navigating (away and then) back to this page.
This ONLY happens on Android. If I click somewhere in the white area, the controls still function but I don't get to see them.

*What did I try*:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    Content = getContentPage();
}


protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    this.Content = null;
}
```

But this doesn't solve the problem.

How do I fix this? What is the problem?

Comment: can you provide sample project with some fake data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go back to previous Page you can use

```
PopAsync()
```

or

```
PopModalAsync()
```

Grab some informations about Xamarin.Forms Navigation here :)
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.INavigation/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when using page navigation, I assume this automatically gets called when you navigate back.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird issue, are you doing something with the view on the next Page? You can always double check the visibility of the view:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    YourView.IsVisible = true;
}


protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    YourView.IsVisible = true;
}
```

If that does not work, use `BackgroundColor` property to detect which of the views is doing this weird issue, maybe for some reason the color's are being changed.

Comment: The .IsVisible did not work, because it was visible all the time. But your BackgroundColor method did! De stacklayout background color gets set somewhere, but I think its strange this only happens on Android?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was generating views from code (which I have to), so for example in page1.xaml I would have a stacklayout with an x:name that I would then populate the children with views via code (generated from a singleton), then when I navigate to page2.xaml I would have another stacklayout that I would populate with views from the same singleton (sometimes with changes). To solve it was messy, I basically created two properties on the singleton that had the views, so when page1's stacklayout gets populated, it received singleton.Views and when I navigate to page2, it would get singleton.ViewsOther, page3 => singleton.Views, page3 => singleton.ViewsOther... and so on. Its messy, but I just needed it to work, you can get a better solution from experts, but just in case this helps someone else who needs a quick fix